# How to show extended icons in the taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10

For example I opened three windows of google chrome browser and two file managers as a result I see it like this

[image]

if you take a closer look you will see that these windows appears one behind others. What I need is to show them one next to other like here

[image]

you see here I opened two file managers and them both one next to other, not behind.

Question is - how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I know if you need the application showing in the taskbar like this.

[image]

If yes, please right click taskbar and select **Taskbar settings**. Then under **Combine taskbar buttons**, please select **Never**.

[image]